# Why Angular pattern validation does not work?

Tags: regex, angular, angular8

I have validation rule:

```
latitude: [null, [Validators.pattern("^\d+\.+\d+$")]],
```

When I enter value: *40.333*

It validates as wrong, why?

**HTML is:**

```
<input
      type="text"
      [ngClass]="{'has-error':form.get('latitude').invalid}"
      formControlName="latitude"
      maxlength="20"
      />
```

Comment: Did you check your RegExp?

Comment: Sure, it works in RegExp, see my updated question

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML code as well.

Comment: I have posted, check pleas

Comment: why you have `+` after `.`, are you willing to allow more than one `.` ?  you should be doing this `^\d+\.\d+$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're passing a string to form a regex (not a regex itself), you need to double escape it.

Try

```
latitude: [null, [Validators.pattern("^\\d+\\.\\d+$")]],
```

The `+` for `.` isn't required since latitude is a decimal value. `.` should appear only once.